# how to install or include opengl library GLUT in Turbo C++ folder to run opengl program

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

My system is running on Windows 7 and my Turbo C++ compiler does not support opengl header files.

So the question is what should I do to run the opengl program in Turbo C++ compiler?.

Comment: Opengl is a 32-bit API, it requires a 32-bit compiler.  Turbo C++ is a 16-bit compiler.  You need a better one.

Comment: Turbo C++ is the one that supports only <iostream.h>? I think you have toupdate to a newer compiler immediately...

Comment: if i update the compiler then how I can install the GLUT in the Preinstalled C++ compiler folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](http://hem.passagen.se/roquero/borland_glut.htm) might help.

Good luck!